# How to prevent ticks from getting too close together for responsive d3 chart

Tags: d3.js

I have a chart with a line plot. The x-axis is dates. The chart is displayed on mobile devices as well as desktop browsers. So the chart needs to scale appropriately. The chart displays user activity. When they are new there is as little as one point on the x-axis. Over time the number of points can grow large.

They problem I'm having is in controlling the number of ticks on the x-axis. The points crunch together too much before d3 decides to show fewer ticks. I'm wondering how I can better control this.

When I set `xaxis.ticks` directly d3 allows the ticks to get too close together. When I set `xaxis.tickValues` I have to do more math than I'd like to control the number of  points. I thought of using tickPadding, but that didn't work either.

I also thought of using d3.time.mondays to show just week boundaries for charts that span a long period of time. But a) that doesn't look good when there are only a small number of points and over a long enough period of time it could run into the same fundamental problem.

So, how do I prevent tick values from getting so close together, generally and specifically for dates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The trick I use still is in setting the number of ticks manually, depending on the width of the window.

And, for a small number of data points, making sure the axis still shows a full day, because it looks better in visualization (I feel):

```
var dataExtendedDates = dataFeverGraph.slice(0);
dataExtendedDates.unshift({
    temperature: 0, 
    date: dataFeverGraph[0].date.substr(0,10) + ' 00:00:00'
});
dataExtendedDates.push({
    temperature: 0, 
    date: dataFeverGraph[dataFeverGraph.length-1].date.substr(0,10) + ' 23:59:59'
});
```

Assume I have a set of data of the form {temperature, date} in the dataFeverGraph variable. I slice it (to create a clone), add midnight of the first date as first element (assuming dataFeverGraph has objects ordered by date, ascending) and 23:59 of the last date as last element. I'll be using the dataFeverGraph dataset for all the normal operations such as creating the line, circles as dots for the data points, etc; but I'll be using the dataExtendedDates for the axis.

So, setting the x-axis with the dataExtendedDates:

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0,width])
        .domain(d3.extent(dataExtendedDates, function(d) { 
              return formatDate.parse(d.date); }));
```

And now just limit the number of ticks on the x-axis, depending on the width:

```
var createXaxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient('bottom')
        .ticks(Math.max(width/50,2));
```

So the ticks(Math.max(width/50,2)) should do the trick. This assumes of course you're initially setting the width depending on the actual width of the window, e.g. like so:

```
var margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left:50 };
var height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var width = document.getElementById("temperature_chart").clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
```

It's not "responsive" yet, but it should create a better looking x-axis on initial render.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @mcProgrammer. I ended up hard-coding the number of ticks as well. It was less disappointing than I expected it to be and it works very well.